# Couple RPG/Two Person Roleplaying?

Tags: game-recommendation, one-on-one

I've been into RPGs for a few years now (mostly D&D 3.5), but I'm a pretty bad DM. My girlfriend likes roleplaying and I was wondering if there are any one-DM, one-PC games? Perhaps some story-focused things with little to no combat or a premade thing for two people?

Comment: Please look at our [tag:system-recommendation] guidelines. As stated, this is entirely too broad.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. There are, in fact, *many* RPGs built for your situation, and without more details about the kind of game you want to play (genre, themes, session/campaign lengths, content, maps/minis or not, are you picky about your randomisation mechanic like what kind of dice? and so forth) it's impossible to give a useful suggestion. Can you please edit in as many details as possible? Look at other [tag:one-on-one] [tag:game-recommendation] questions to see what kind of information to offer.

Comment: Also if you get enough rep come into the chat and people will be more than happy to chatter about recommendations :)